# My sessionscoped bean does not have values stored on every refresh

Tags: jsf, session-scope

I have a SessionScoped Bean which consists of a list and a flag. The list populates a datatable in the xhtml view. 
On first load, the list is populated. Every other load should not repopulate the list but it does despite the check. This behaviour also holds for postbacks on commandLinks clicks.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "customerSegmentInfo")
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerSegmentInfo extends BasePage implements Serializable {
private boolean isNBACalled = false;
private List<NextBestActionDTO> nextBestActionList = null;

public List<NextBestActionDTO> getNextBestActionList() {
        log.debug("----- nbaCalled: " + isNBACalled);
        if(nextBestActionList == null && !isNBACalled){
            log.debug("-------- getNextBestAction");
            try {
                nextBestActionList = this.getNbaService().getNextBestAction(this.getCustomerInfo().getCountryCode(), this.getCustomerInfo().getCustomerNo());
                log.debug("---- " + nextBestActionList.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                log.debug("------ error calling nba service bean " + e);
            }
            isNBACalled = true;
            log.debug("----- nbaCalled: " + isNBACalled);
        }
        return nextBestActionList;
    }

    public void setNextBestActionList(List<NextBestActionDTO> nextBestActionList) {
        this.nextBestActionList = nextBestActionList;
    }
}
```

As the list is not null from last page load and flag also set to true, the call getNextBestAction shouldnt be made, but in logs the flag is false and apparently the list is null too. 
the behaviour is irregular
On certain loads it behaves as expected on others not.

I Tried setting the javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD context parameter in the web.xml to both server and client, nothing changed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What package did you import the `@SessionScoped` annotation from?

Comment: @BalusC import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

Comment: I have noticed that the bean is being recreated on the refresh. the constructor and init methods get called hence the properties are being set to null. But i dont understand why ?